# how i used special characters in html content in php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<p>This is Jhone's home.</p>
```

This is not display in my front site. but

When I use `<p>This is Jhone\'s home.</p>` It display.

I need to put without backslash. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

**htmlspecialchars will help you out.**

```
<?php
$str = "<p>This is Jhone's home.</p>";
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Sulthan

Thanks for reply but how to use this function with textarea field in form

Comment: Just put the inside the <textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($str); ?> </textarea>

Comment: Thank you but not working this function properly.<p>This is Jhone's home.</p> I want to this code fetch to my front site and insert to my database from textarea field. when i am going to save my form but nothing to display in database and on front site.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ENT_QUOTES` as the second argument to [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) will convert the quotations marks. Also, it is extremely important to provide the correct charset.

```
echo htmlspecialchars("This is Jhone's home.", ENT_QUOTES', 'UTF-8');
```

The translations that are performed are:

```
'&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
"'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

So if you view the source on the browser, your output will be this:

```
This is Jhone&quot;s home.
```